# Firestore rules not working using displayName, swift - iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have firestore rules like this:

```
 match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.name == "dummyUser";

}
```

I am logging in anonymous user, and on complete I set the name, (lets say "dummyUser"). Here is the code:

```
func signInUserAnonymously(callback: @escaping ((Bool) )->Void){

print("2124.AuthFirebaseHelper: Signing in user anonymously")

Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error)  in

    if let error = error {
        print("2124.AuthFirebaseHelper: Sign in failed:", error.localizedDescription)


    } else {
        print ("2124.AuthFirebaseHelper: Signed in successfully anonymously")

        // set users name (to allow database reads)

        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = "dummyUser"

        changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in

                 callback(true)

            })


        }

    }

}
```

Now, if I test the users display name in the code, I see that it is successfully changed to "dummyUser". However, the firestore request doesn't work, and I get the message in the log:

Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is my request:

```
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Constants.DB_VALUES_COLLECTION).document(Constants.DB_GLOBAL_VALUES_DOCUMENT)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
 if let document = document, document.exists {
      let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
      print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
  } else {
      print("Document does not exist")
  }
}
```

When I delete this rule (and allow anyone to read), then it works. Why is this not letting me read from the database, if this is the users display name. I have tried calling:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
```

but it still doesn't work.

This is working fine on Android, and only on ios (using swift), I have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using display name as the criteria in security rules?  That seems fragile.  If you want to identify a specific user, the best way to do that is with their UID.

Comment: In the meantime, thats the security rule I'm using. Do you know why I'm having this problem? Thanks!